# HDD Docking station for SSD drive

Tags: docking-station

I want to use USB3/SATA III HDD Docking station for a SATA III SSD drive. I've noticed that this product is not described as a 'HDD/SSD docking station', but rather just described as a 'HDD Docking station'. So my question is:

Is it 100% certain that those SATA III HDD docking stations would be compatible with SATA III SSD Drives?

Comment: No one will guarantee tjlhis for you, but it would be very strange indeed  if it didn't work, as these things just talk SATA, and ssd's present the same as HDDs. I've used a few, and never had any issues.

Comment: @davidgo Why wouldn't anyone guarantee this, as SATA, and it's connectors, are standardized and backward compatible, so it will always work _(could there potentially be a dock out there so out of spec it wouldn't work, sure, but that's a rarity due to QA)_. The only thing that matters would be voltage and it would matter only for 3.5" HDDs, not SSDs _(3.5" uses 12V, 2.5" uses 5V)_.

Comment: @JW0914 - **_most_** 2.5" disks only use 5v, not necessarily all... There's also 3.3v to consider, which some disks require (typically some enterprise or "_external_")... The availability of additional commands like TRIM is also potentially a large concern, especially for SSDs.

Comment: @jw0914 Because we are sticking our necks out guaranteeing something we have no control over. In addition to Attire advice, internal disks present slightly differently to external ones (as smart cant always be read on these docks, what else doesnt pass through?) and its conceivable to me that the high iops might conceivably not work well with some drivers. Effectively there could be edge cases.

Comment: @davidgo SATA is SATA... What you're inferring makes zero sense if applied to any other standardized communication protocol... I suppose USB cables can't be guaranteed to work (in this context), or serial connections. Users may not want to get an Ethernet hub because that may not work with Ethernet traffic. Come on now... Attie, TRIM is either supported by the drive's firmware or it's not - how the connection is made doesn't matter, only if the user has software that can issue a TRIM command

Comment: @jw0914 But SATA!=USB. Have a read of http://salutepc.altervista.org/ssd-on-usb-3-0-3-1-with-trim-support-windows-linux.html and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52604/can-i-get-s-m-a-r-t-support-on-external-hard-drives which both show not all functionality of SATA works on all USB docking stations.

Comment: @davidgo The question has zero to do with what features will or will not work, but with whether a SSD SATA drive will work in a HDD dock and the answer is an unequivocal yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it 100% certain that those SATA III HDD docking stations would be compatible with SATA III SSD Drives?

No, but it's also not 100% certain that **all** spinning HDDs would be fully compatible with it either.

It would however, be *very* unlikely for a SATA device to not operate *at all* when connected, regardless of the physical storage medium.

---

If it's a "*toaster*" style (as shown below), then you may find it awkward to correctly mate the 2.5" disk in a 3.5" hole. For this reason, many of them have the flaps shown that help to align the connector correctly, and stabilise the disk while it's connected. If you don't have the flap, then just align the disk in the connector's corner.

[image]

---

If in any doubt or if you have the option, then prefer a UAS / UASP ([USB Attached SCSI Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI)) model over the older MSC / BOT ([Mass Storage Class / Bulk-Only Transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class)) devices - you will usually see a performance increase and the disk will be more "*directly*" accessible to the host system.

The SATA link does carry a number of different logical commands for SSDs (e.g: [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing))), and these won't by supported by the MSC / BOT enclosures. These extra commands should be supported by UAS enclosures, assuming your host system supports and uses them correctly too.

If you're looking at a more "*intelligent*" unit, like a NAS or external RAID enclosure, then you may also run into issues with TRIM commands not being issued correctly (and the degraded performance associated), but the disk should still be accessible and operational in the short term.

---

My comment above regarding "*all spinning HDDs*" not necessarily being compatible has two main components to it:

- Some spinning hard disks now employ [SMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording), and as such a subset of these disks also support the TRIM command mentioned above. If the TRIM commands aren't correctly issued, then performance can suffer.
- As with all technology, components are designed to a specification. It's possible that two devices can be designed at the extremeties, either end of the acceptable range, resuling in incompatibilities with one another. This is a rare situation to find yourself in, and given the relatively small number of storage manufacturers, will likely be seen as an issue with the enclosure not the disk.

In addition to this, there are number of other points that may affect operation, depending on the particular parts in use:

- Support for additional commands, like TRIM (as above)
- Support for [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)
- Power requirements (i.e: delivering enough power for operation - high speed SSDs can actually have relatively high peak power usage)
- Voltage requirements (i.e: supplying 3.3v and/or 12v, in addition to the 5v)
- High IOPS and throughput specifications of the storage device will likely be significantly impacted when operating via USB

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that any USB SATA hard drive dock is compatible with both SATA SSDs and SATA HDDs.